# One part of Fragment layout is not showing in Activity

Tags: android, xml

I have 2 **fragments** in Main Activity when I click on first fragment's FAB it will be replaced with the second fragment, when I pressed back button in Fragment 2nd it will back on Fragment 1st, but it not show one big part of the layout, look this images to understand the problem:

[1: When the app launched](https://pasteboard.co/IqmoEIV.png)

[2: when I pressed back button in 2nd fragment and cames back to 1st fragment](https://pasteboard.co/IqmoUUl.png)

In 1st fragment xml I have 3 part main Item:

```
   <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
             ...
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
             ...
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton/>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
```

actually, NestedScrollview and its subItems Not show when I came back from 2nd fragment to 1st fragment.

In Fragment 1st I start Fragment 2nd with these codes:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fabAddWord);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(TAG)
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, SecondFragment.newInstance(), 
                            WordSearchFragment.class.getSimpleName())
                    .commit();            
            }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days I solved the problem, The problem Was for **FrameLayout** That I used as **Fragment Container**. I learned Use FrameLayout as Container and see in everywhere that people use Framelayout, but in fact, FrameLayot not adapted for complex Layout Fragments.
So in **MainActivity.xml**, I changed **FrameLayout** To **ConstraintLayout** and worked!

Answer (score 0):

you should override the onBackPressed and show the first fragment when the back button pressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) 
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    else 
       super.onBackPressed();
}
```